# Laravel mass change Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the `users`, `promocodes` and `users_promocodes` tables. Models: `User`, `Promocode` and `UserPromocode`.

They are the keys of `users_promocodes` table: `user_id` -> `users.id`, `promocode_id` -> `promocodes.id`

And when I delete the promocode from base, I need to take away the promocode bonus.
How can I set by Eloquent `users.bonus` (`users.bonus - 5`) value for users, who have the `users_promocodes.id = 10`?

Comment: How did you set up the relationships and can you explain the last part better?

Comment: @Phiter relationship wasn't set by laravel.
I need to explore that query by Eloquent, is it possible?
`UPDATE users SET bonus = (bonus - 5)  FROM users_promocodes WHERE users_promocodes.user_id = users.id AND users_promocodes.promocode_id = 10`

Comment: @MyZik for better understanding please add your database model (or at least of the related tables), your controller code and also explain better the last part. You metion `UserPromocodes` but not how the bonuses work.

Comment: @HCK in model I have only `protected $table` :)
please, look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912585/laravel-mass-change-eloquent#comment84833498_48912779

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [Model Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers) to track these kind of changes.

When PromoCodes are deleted, you can query on the `users` table and update as needed:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

class PromoCodeObserver
{
    /**
     * Listen to the PromoCode Deleting event.
     *
     * @param  PromoCode $promoCode
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleting(PromoCode $promoCode)
    {
        // search for all users associated with the promo code
        // update the bonus and save changes
        $promoCode->users->each(function (User $user) { 
            $user->update(['bonus' => $user->bonus - 5]);
        });
    }
}

// User.php
public function promocode()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(PromoCode::class);
}

// PromoCode.php
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

Assuming a User can only have one PromoCode you'll need the above one-to-many relationship, just add a `promo_code_id` field on `users` if that is the case.

Comment: Call to a member function each() on null :((

Comment: I think that I need to create method `users` in my PromoCode model. But what it will looks?

Comment: Oh, use `deleting` rather than `deleted`. Stupid mistake in the example there.

Comment: have a similar problem :(

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the 2nd comment you left, yes you'll need to create a relationship between promo codes and users. I will update the answer

Comment: thanks for your answer.
But now I have a problem: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.promocode_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`promocode_id` = 8 and `users`.`promocode_id` is not null)`